# Не корректно выводит сумму водных

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
int i;
int summ=0;
    for(i=1; i < argc; i++){
        printf ("%d: %s\n" ,i,argv[i]);
        int g = (int)argv[i];
        summ = summ + g;

    }
    printf ("%d\n" ,summ);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Но при чём тут bash?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Брр... `int g = (int)argv[i];` - и как это, по-вашему, работает?...

```
int g = atoi(argv[i]);
```

Например, так...

Comment: Не знаю синтексиса, что посоветуете по самообучению?

Comment: @Виктор Классика - Керниган & Ритчи "Язык программирования С". ИМХО, лучше ничего не придумали.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду искать